# Oracle : SUM values between max and min dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum, max

I am struggling with a query and think I need some help.
An example of the data I use : 
[image]

I need to sum the values between the max DATE of each year that have the O (zero) TYPE.
The results should be :

```
YEAR - SUM
2015 - 10
2016 - 20
2017 - 20
2018 - 35
```

The sum must include lines with TYPE 1 or 2 but these lines cannot be used in the identification of the MAX DATE by year.
To be clear, in the data I provided, if we had
[image]

then the max DATE for 2018 would be 05/07/2018 and the results of the query :

```
YEAR - SUM
2015 - 10
2016 - 20
2017 - 20
2018 - 30
```

Identifying max value per year isn't a problem but excluding 1 and 2 TYPEs and then summing data is where I'm stuck at.

thanks in advance.

EDIT : correction of the results.

EDIT2 : another example

[image]

The expected results

```
YEAR - SUM
2015 - 10
2016 - 20
2017 - 20
2018 - 30
```

[image]

The expected results

```
YEAR - SUM
2015 - 10
2016 - 20
2017 - 20
2018 - 38
```

Comment: What does "max date" have to do with this?  Why is 2018 "20" and not "30" in the second example?

Comment: Corrected the results. In the first example, 25 becomes 35 and in the second, 20 becomes 30. As explained below, VALUES must be included in the sum only if they are not the max dates of the year.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "max date" has to do with this.  You seem to want:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY') as yr, sum(value)
from t
where type = 0
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY')
order by to_char(date, 'YYYY');
```

EDIT:

If you want both the max date and the sum, then use conditional aggregation:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY') as yr, max(date) as max_date,
       sum(case when type = 0 then value end) as sum_type0
from t
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY')
order by to_char(date, 'YYYY');
```

Comment: "The sum must include lines with TYPE 1 or 2 but these lines cannot be used in the identification of the MAX DATE by year."

Comment: @Corion . . . This works for the first example.  I'm pretty sure that 2018 should be 30 and not 20 in the second.

Comment: But only by luck - I think if the TYPE 1 entry had a nonzero value, your calculation would be off in the eye of the OP. But maybe the OP should clarify - @KMarron, can you please add more examples?

Comment: Instead of `to_char(date, 'YYYY')` you can also use `TRUNC(date, 'YYYY')`

Comment: Complicated to explain. In the first example, VALUES with TYPE 1 and 2 are included in the sum because they are not the max or min DATE of the year. In the second example, 10/10/2018 is excluded because of its TYPE 2 despite it's the max date of 2018. Then 05/07/2018 is exluded of the sum because of its TYPE 1, even though it's the second max date (juste after 10/10/2018).